# Is there a way to nest an array inside of an object using the name attribute within a form?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am building an full-stack application in where I have a form submitting data to one of my post routes. On this form, I have all of my input fields bundled into `req.body.model`, thanks to the fact that I can add a name attribute with square brackets around the key, like so `name="model[height]"`.

This should equate to something like this:

```
model = {
    height: //value,
    weight: //value,
    age: //value
}
```

However, I want one of the values to be an empty array so I can push URLS into the array, like so:

```
model = {
    height: //value,
    weight: //value,
    age: //value,
    urls: [//urls here]
}
```

Since you can automatically create an object using the name attribute, I was wondering if there was a way to create a nested array using the name attribute as well?

## Code snippet

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="model[height]">
    <input type="text" name="model[weight]">
    <input type="text" name="model[age]">

    // these 2 inputs would go into the urls key in the models object
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">


    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Not sure if I worded this properly...but let me know if I can explain in further detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass index next to the property you can create an array. Something like this

```
 // these 2 inputs would go into the urls key in the models object
    <input type="text" name="model[urls][0]">
    <input type="text" name="model[urls][1]">
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for...came so close. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got what you are trying to do exactly, but it seems like you can first process the submitted data and then send the processed data to wherever you want to send it. It's a bit more verbose, but I feel like it may give you more flexibility when organising your data. So maybe you can do something like this:

**html**

```
<form name="model">
  <input type="text" id="height">
  <input type="text" id="weight">
  <input type="text" id="age">
  <input type="text" id="url1">
  <input type="text" id="url2">
  <button onclick="processForm()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**script**

```
function processForm() {

    let height = document.querySelector("#height").value;
    let weight = document.querySelector("#weight").value;
    let age = document.querySelector("#age").value;
    let url1 = document.querySelector("#url1").value;
    let url2 = document.querySelector("#url2").value;

    let model = {
      "height": height,
      "weight": weight,
      "age": age,
      "url": [url1, url2]
    }

    // now you can send model object to where it is needed
}
```